# Inflate ListView row from OnClickListener in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a class (`A_Main.java`) extending `ArrayAdapter`. I set my `ListView` to use `A_Main` as it's `ListAdapter`. Inside `A_Main.getView()` I inflate the view to get at the `ListView` widgets for each row. Each row contains a `TextView`, `CheckBox` and an `ImageButton`. When the `ImageButton` is clicked, I play the song associated with the `TextView`. I don't want to use `onItemClickListener()` on the `ListView` as it's too easy to fumble up a scroll and start playing a new song.

When I click an `ImageButton` in a new row, I need to un-hilite the `ImageButton` of the currently playing song, and hilite the new one.  I'm thinking the way to do that would be to inflate the view in the ImageButton's `onClickListener()` and un-hilite every button in the List, then, hi-lite the one which is playing. I'm not sure the best way to go about this.  Can I keep a member list in `A_Main` of each `ImageButton` ID as getView() iterates over them and reference the ID directly from `onClickListener()` without causing memory leaks? Do those IDs disappear as soon as `getView()` is done with them? Any thoughts on alternative approaches?

[image]

Comment: What about Taking a drawable selector..?

Comment: A selector won't maintain state. It's only useful for the button animation at the time of click/touch. Unless there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

Solution is probably simple Take boolean array globally like this

```
 private final boolean[] selectedstates;
```

And initialize it with the size of your list in your constructor

```
 selectedstates= new boolean[yourlist.size()];
```

And in out side of onclick listener set like this

```
 yourbutton.setSelected(selectedstates[position]);
```

I hope this will help you

---

Try this

Take a custom selector with two different state images for selection and non selection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause_button"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button" />
</selector>
```

1.Create a global variable

```
Imageview previous;
```

in your Custom Adapter and Initialize it in the constructor where you'll get the content

```
previous=new ImageView(context);
```

Add in your adapter getView() method you will probably have a onclickListener for your Imageview 
do like this

```
 imagPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ImageView current=((ImageView)v);
              current.setSelected(true);
              previous.setSelected(false);
              previous=current;
        }
    });
```

This will work, I was confident because I have used it in my app. I hope this will help you

Comment: After some testing, the ListView isn't updating button states correctly when scrolled. Some buttons appear selected which haven't been.  What are you using in getView() to correct button state?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, it was night in India so I went to sleep yesterday...I'll update answer..

Comment: No problem. Funny! I ended up implementing the exact same thing you suggested. Thanks for following-up.

Answer (score 1):

Should look at this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. Especially the viewholder part to reuse views and avoid memory leaks. To highlight a listview row button check the position of the item on which you click and highlight the button by setting a background for the button.

Comment: Thanks, great video! I've implemented the ViewHolder class it talks about. I always suspected the constant findViewById() calls were a performance hit but never knew what to do about .