# change listview item background when clicke

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a  listview and i want to when i click on a row, its background changes to blue. i use this code:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        }

                    });
```

this works wit some wrong. when i click on first item, it turns to blue but item #3 and #5 changes to blue too!!! i cant understand why!!  i just want only selected item turns to blue!!!

Comment: use selectors ( search about them )

Comment: Try this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253987/inflate-listview-row-from-onclicklistener-in-android/15254297#15254297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to use selectors? They works properly and provide clean solution.

**listselector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
 
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/hover" 
        />
    
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/hover" />
</selector>
```

**normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
     >
    <solid 
        android:color="#cccccc"
        />
</shape>
```

**hover.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
     >
    <solid 
        android:color="#dddddd"
        />
</shape>
```

### An Usage

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"
/>
```

Key property is to set `android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"` for your `ListView`.

### Note:

You can use in shape also gradient property instead of solid color. And for more details also you can look at tutorial [Android Custom ListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).

Comment: it works but when i tap on a row color change but when i focus out from row color resets. i want color change permanently. how  i can do this

Comment: Hi, Still the background is changed on item click only. And I am using custom adaptor how can i change the selected item-view textview color???

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom list view then use the below code.

```
  public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
final ViewHolder vh;
vh= new ViewHolder();

if(arg1==null )
{
                arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lyourcustomlayouttobe inflated, arg2,false);//custom layout inflated
        arg1.setTag(vh);
        }

return arg1;
```

}

Your custom layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
 android:background="@drawable/listviewbkg">
 //other items to be inlfated.
 </LinearLayout>
```

Create a drawable folder under resources. post the below xml as listviewbkg

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
 <item  android:state_focused="false" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
 </selector>
```

Shape when normal under drawable with name normal.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>//change color    
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#0FECFF" /><!-- #330000FF #ffffffff -->//border color
   <gradient                               // remove the gradient if do not wish to use.
    android:startColor="#ffffffff" 
    android:endColor="#110000FF" 
    android:angle="90"/> 

    <padding android:left="5dp"
     android:top="5dp"
     android:right="5dp"
     android:bottom="5dp"/> 
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"      // change this to increase the rounded edge radius
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
     </shape>
```

Shape when pressed under the name pressed.xml in drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>    //change color 
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#0FECFF"/>//border color
  <padding android:left="5dp"
     android:top="5dp"
     android:right="5dp"
     android:bottom="5dp"/> 
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"// increase the radius at the edge
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
  </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

use listselectors to achieve this goal:

Hree is an example:
http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html

and if you want your listview item color permanent, then, you need to create an `array` of selected positions, an in `getview()` method of your cutom adapter, you need to check if that position is exists in array or not, if yes, then change background color of your view manually