# setBackgroundColor for listView item not working on JellyBean

Tags: android, android-listview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a listView with a custom adapter. I've made the listView item's background change color when selected. This works perfectly on Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4 on Samsung Galaxy S2 and on ICS 4.0.3 on emulator. But it does not work on 4.2.2 JellyBean emulator. On JB, when an item is selected it's background stays as it was before.

This is a portion of my code where I have the logic for setting background color when item is selected:

```
private int mItemIndex = -1;

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;           
        ....

        if (convertView == null) {
            ....
            ....

        } else {
            /* To highlight the selected item */
            if (position == mItemIndex) {
                convertView.setSelected(true);
                convertView.setPressed(true);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.SkyBlue));
            } else {
                convertView.setSelected(false);
                convertView.setPressed(false);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.WhiteSmoke));
            }
            /* To highlight the selected item - end */

            ....
            ....

        return v;
    }
```

Alternatively, I tried 
`convertView.setBackgroundResource(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.SkyBlue));` instead of setBackgroundColor and it didn't work too.

Is there a workaround for getting this to work on Jellybean? 
Or am I missing something in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253987/inflate-listview-row-from-onclicklistener-in-android/15254297#15254297

Comment: do you only need this color change to highlight the selected item in a ListView?

Comment: @Pragnani, thanks. I see that you are telling me to have a boolean array to keep tack of the state but I don't fully understand how to implement it in my scenario. From my activity which has the listView I call, `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
         {public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
              ((TransactionListAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).setSelectItem(arg2);
          }
         });` and the `setSelectItem()` sets `mItemIndex` with the passed in arg2. Should I have the boolean array in my adapter class?

Comment: @Maver1ck, yes the color change highlights the selected item. I have buttons on the actionbar which I can click to do stuff on the selected item.

Comment: @RBK Answer it self has the whole code, how to implement, check the answer below edit, you'll find your self the answer

Comment: @Pragnani, btw I don't have an onClick listner in my adapter but an setOnItemClickListner in my list view activity's onCreate.

Comment: @RBK Same logic applies here... I'll post the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a custom selector with two different state images for selection and non selection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause_button"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button" />
</selector>
```

1.Create a global variable in your activity

`View previous;` (Take your viewgroup of listrow)

And in your onCreate method initialize like this after setContentView

```
previous=new View(context);
```

And in your onItemClick listener of listView do like this

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    view.setSelected(true);
                                       previous.setSelected(false);
                                        previous=current;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Currently I don't have a custom selector but a custom view for the listview's row: https://gist.github.com/bharatkrishna/5175158

I will see how I can convert this into a selector. Sorry I am an amateur in Android dev. Will try it & post my comment here.  Thanks.

Comment: @RBK If you don't have the idea on Custom Drawable selector then, directly set the background color instead of setSelected, i.e in the above answer, view.setBackgroundColor(yourcolor); , for the previous set the color of the normal listitem when it is not highlighted

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said and it works. Here is my setOnItemClickListner: http://pastebin.com/4CPwicb0.


Btw, in your answer, I think you meant `previous=view` and not `previous=current`.